# Android: How to run monkeyrunner script from command prompt

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

How to run a script from command prompt I was trying to open a file by following syntax but I got error.

Command:

```
android-sdk\tools>monkeyrunner test.py
```

Error:

```
Can't open specified script file Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE -s MonkeyServer IP Address. -p MonkeyServer TCP Port. -v MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF) –
```

Can any one tell me, how will I run a monkeyrunner script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the error message, it can't find 'test.py' - is it in the folder where you're running monkeyrunner, is that folder on the path, and do you have read permissions set?

Comment: Yes, I did not paste the file in that folder.

Comment: Polluting android sdk installation with local scripts does not seem to be a good idea and they might be lost during upgrades

Answer (score 1):

MonkeyRunner looks for the script local to itself

try:

> monkeyrunner test.py